# How to declare a Qt class derived from QApplication and override the notify function?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I am trying to override the notify function in a class derived from QApplication:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>
#include <typeinfo>

class Application final : public QApplication
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    Application(int& argc, char** argv) : QApplication(argc, argv) { }
    virtual bool notify(QObject *receiver, QEvent *e) override;
};

bool Application::notify(QObject* receiver, QEvent* event)
{
    try
    {
        return QApplication::notify(receiver, event);
    }
    catch (std::exception &e)
    {
        qFatal("Error %s sending event %s to object %s (%s)",
            e.what(), typeid(*event).name(), qPrintable(receiver->objectName()),
            typeid(*receiver).name());
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        qFatal("Error <unknown> sending event %s to object %s (%s)",
            typeid(*event).name(), qPrintable(receiver->objectName()),
            typeid(*receiver).name());
    }
    return false;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Application a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

But I get a compilation error in the class declaration:

```
error: undefined reference to `vtable for Application'
```

What is the correct way to declare this class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#Q_OBJECT):

> **Q_OBJECT**
>
> The Q_OBJECT macro must appear in the private section of a class
>   definition that declares its own signals and slots or that uses other
>   services provided by Qt's meta-object system.

In your case you are not creating any signal or slot so it is not necessary, delete it.

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>

class Application final: public QApplication{
public:
    using QApplication::QApplication;
    bool notify(QObject *receiver, QEvent *e) override;
};

bool Application::notify(QObject* receiver, QEvent* event)
{
    try
    {
        return QApplication::notify(receiver, event);
    }
    catch (std::exception &e)
    {
        qFatal("Error %s sending event %s to object %s (%s)",
            e.what(), typeid(*event).name(), qPrintable(receiver->objectName()),
            typeid(*receiver).name());
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        qFatal("Error <unknown> sending event %s to object %s (%s)",
            typeid(*event).name(), qPrintable(receiver->objectName()),
            typeid(*receiver).name());
    }
    return false;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Application a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

If in Application you are going to create signals or slots then Q_OBJECT if it is mandatory, this macro will generate a `main.moc` file that you must include in the **main.cpp**.

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>

class Application final: public QApplication{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    using QApplication::QApplication;
    bool notify(QObject *receiver, QEvent *e) override;
};

bool Application::notify(QObject* receiver, QEvent* event)
{
    [...]
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Application a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}

#include "main.moc" // <---
```

Then execute **Run qmake** that is in the **Build** menu, and then compile.

**Note:**

If you move the Application to a .h file it is not necessary to include the moc since qmake will do it in the Makefile that you create.